# How to find out which methods I should add in Swift?

Tags: swift

I'm new to Swift programming and have a question when you write code. I was just following one Udemy course and trying to make a table view. But the problem is, whenever I write code using Swift, I'm still not sure how to figure out which methods I should add (in this case 2 tableView() methods). I want to know how do you find out which methods you write in Swift? In the case below, I added

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return routineArr.count
    }
```

and

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyRoutineCell", for: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel?.text = routineArr[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }
```

but I saw there are a lot of methods for tableView. How do you know those are the methods you want to add in order to appear a table view and items?

I just copied the code so here is what I got.

```
    import UIKit

    class MyRoutineViewController: UITableViewController {
    
    let routineArr = ["eat", "wash", "sleep"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
   
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return routineArr.count
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyRoutineCell", for: indexPath)
        
        cell.textLabel?.text = routineArr[indexPath.row]
        
        return cell
    }

}
```

Sorry for the stupid question. I came from web development, and recently I'm trying mobile development using Swift. I feel the basic syntax is similar to other programming languages, but when I make an app, I always struggle to find which methods are needed. When I watch a Udemy video or YouTube, instructors are like "we want to add XYZ, so we use ABC method in this case", but I'm not sure how to find the methods from scratch...
So, I would love to know any resources when you work on Swift programming and make an app. Thanks...

Comment: it's in the documentation for UITableView from Apple. Using the Apple frameworks is not actually, strictly speaking, a Swift issue. But copying other code and trying it out is a good way to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These methods are defined in a couple UITableView-related [protocols](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Protocols.html). Since your class derives from [UITableViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcontroller), it inherits default implementations of some of these protocol methods, which you can override in your class. You can read about all the different protocol methods in the [UITableViewDataSource](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdatasource) and [UITableViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate) documentation.

Apple also has guides for using UITableView which will cover higher level concepts:

- [Table Views overview](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/views_and_controls/table_views)
- [Filling a Table with Data](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/views_and_controls/table_views/filling_a_table_with_data)